# Cmake : include FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake

Tags: module, cmake

In many cmake find modules, we find `INCLUDE("${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake")`
I would like to do the same thing but from the CMakeLists of my project.
The problem is that `${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}` is pointing to the directory of my project... And `FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake` is in `/usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/`.

Is there a CMake variable that is pointing to the cmake module directory ?
If not, how to do that in my CMakeLists (I want that to be portable and not to be "hardcoded") ?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If a module file is specified, the [include](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/include.html) command will search the CMake module directory automatically. Just use:

```
include(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)
```

Comment: That does not work if you added a directory to `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`

Answer (score 2):

If you've changed the `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` variable (which is usually the case when creating a custom `Find*.cmake`), you can do:

`include(${CMAKE_ROOT}/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)`

Comment: I found that I had to specify the file extension: `include(${CMAKE_ROOT}/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake)`